# How do I make a map of modals that open onClick for each map of buttons?

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, react-hooks, array.prototype.map

I currently have a functional component like the following, where I
generate several buttons from the `useValues()` hook.

```
const ButtonsWithModals = () => {
  const [objects, loading] = useObjects() // `loading` is used in my `App` HOC
  const [isModalOpen, setModalOpen] = React.useState()
  const [modal, setModal] = React.useState([])
  
  const ref = React.useRef()
  
  function onClickOutside() {
    setModalOpen(false)
  }
  
  useClickOutside(ref, onClickOutside)
  
  return (
    <>
      {isModalOpen ? (
        <RenderModal ref={ref} key={modal} objectValue3={object.value3} />
        ) : (
        objects.map((object, index) => (
          <button
            style={{size: "" + object.value3}} 
            onClick={() => setModalOpen(true) setModal(index)}
          >
            <p>{object.value2}</p>
          </button>
        ))
        )
      }
    </>
  )
}
```

The `useVObjects()` hook fetches and returns a list of objects that I render as buttons with `values.map((object, index) {...})`.

My struggle arises when I try to render a modal that is unique to the specific button that a user clicks.

Here is what my `<RenderModal/>` component logic looks like:

```
const RenderModal = ({ref, key, objectValue}) => {
  
  return (
    <>
      <div class="modal">
        <div ref={ref} key={key}>
          <p>{objectValue}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

What I want to have happen when a modal is open is for my `RenderModal` component to display info of the object depending on which button was clicked, so something like this:

```
{isModalOpen ? (
        <RenderModal ref={ref} key={modal} objectValue3={objects.value3} />
        ...
```

where `objectValue3` and `objects.value3` change based on the button that the user clicks.
I've tried many different things and have been referencing these 4 StackOverflow posts, but they use classes and I'm unsure of how to replicate the desired effect with hooks:

- [ReactJS: Open only selected modal popup of map items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50803918/reactjs-open-only-selected-modal-popup-of-map-items)
- [Opening specific components through onClick event - REACT.JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60010628/opening-specific-components-through-onclick-event-react-js)
- [multiple modal in .map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48947584/multiple-modal-in-map)
- [React - Render Item inside map function by click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45779445/react-render-item-inside-map-function-by-click-event)

Answer (score 0):

Try switching the Modal to a component that uses the Context API. Here's an example that allows you to pass in a component for the content of your modal as well as any additional props.

https://codesandbox.io/s/modal-context-api-7yk3b

```
import { useModal } from "../Modal";

const ModalEnglishContent = (props) => <div>Hello, {props.name}!</div>;
const ModalGermanContent = (props) => <div>Guten Tag, {props.name}!</div>;
const ModalSpanishContent = (props) => <div>Buenos días, {props.name}</div>;

const Example = () => {
  const { showModal } = useModal();

  function showModalEnglish() {
    showModal(ModalEnglishContent, { name: "Sam" });
  }

  function showModalGerman() {
    showModal(ModalGermanContent, { name: "Gunter" });
  }

  function showModalSpanish() {
    showModal(ModalSpanishContent, { name: "Jose" });
  }

  return (
    <section>
      <header>
        <h1>Example</h1>
      </header>
      <button onClick={showModalEnglish}>Show English Modal</button>
      <button onClick={showModalGerman}>Show German Modal</button>
      <button onClick={showModalSpanish}>Show Spanish Modal</button>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Example;
```

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was something quick and dirty. I believe there is a more optimal way of achieving what I want to achieve after reviewing Robin Wieruch's [tutorial on React CSS](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-css-styling#css-in-css-css-in-react).

Here's my main `CardsAndModals` functional component logic with hooks:

```js
const CardsAndModals = () => {
  const [objects] = useObjects()

  const [isModalOpen, setModalOpen] = React.useState(false)
  const [modal, setModal] = React.useState(null)
  
  /* Lists of property values for each object */
  let objectValues1 = objects.map(object => object.value1)
  let objectValues2 = objects.map(object => object.value2)
  let objectValues3 = objects.map(object => object.value3)
  let objectValues4 = objects.map(object => object.value4)
  
  // used when calling `useClickOutside()` hook
  const ref = React.useRef()  
  
  function onClickOutside() {
    setModalOpen(false)
  }
  
  function handleOnClick(index) {
    setModalOpen(true)
    setModal(index)
  }
 
  useClickOutside(ref, onClickOutside)
  
  return (
    <>
      {objects.map((object, index) => (
        <button
          class="card" 
          style={{size: "" + object.value3}} 
          onClick={() => handleOnClick(index)}
        >
          <p>{object.value1}</p>
          <p class="helper-text">Click for more info!</p>
        </button>
      ))
      }
      {isModalOpen && setModal != null ? (
        <RenderModal 
          ref={ref} 
          key={modal} 
          objectValue1={objectValues1[modal]}
          objectValue2={objectValues2[modal]}
          objectValue3={objectValues3[modal]}
          objectValue4={objectValues4[modal]}
        />
      ) : (
        ""  
      )}
    </>
  )
}
```

Lastly, here is my refactored `RenderModals` functional component (assume `objectValue1` === name):

```js
const RenderModal = ({ref, key, objectName, objectValue2, objectValue3, objectValue4, objectParagraph}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div class="modal-backdrop">
          <div class="modal-content" ref={ref} key={key}>
            <h1 class="object-info-header">
              {objectName}
            </h1>
            <p class="object-info-value2">
              value2: {objectValue2}
            </p>
            <p class="object-info-value3">
              value3: {objectValue3}
            </p>
            <p class="object-info-value4">
              value4: {objectValue4}
            </p><br />
            <div class="object-info-paragraph">
              <p>
                Here could hold more info about the object 
                <strong>{" " + objectName}</strong>,
                pulled from another API (e.g., Wikipedia):
              </p><br />
              <p>Did you know?</p>
              <p>
                <em>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing
                  elit. Curabitur in viverra turpis. Vivamus id
                  pretium sapien, eu rhoncus ligula. Nam magna ante,
                  viverra ac neque at, volutpat finibus arcu. 
                  Pellentesque at rutrum lacus. Vivamus efficitur, 
                  urna quis pulvinar vehicula, ligula justo mollis 
                  dolor, vitae lacinia lectus erat at purus. Duis 
                  ac tortor nunc. Etiam nulla lacus, posuere sit 
                  amet lectus eu, pellentesque iaculis ipsum. 
                  Curabitur vel velit commodo, vestibulum mi a,
                  imperdiet dui.
                </em>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Sharing this because I wish I had something this detailed out there. Hopefully, this helps some of you!